# Adding figures in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, onlinebanking

In an atm project with a disconnected access database how do you add(lodge) or minus(withdraw) a figure from the balance column which is of type number in the database.

Comment: Please provide some code and your research.

Comment: And also a specific question.

Comment: An Update statement?

Comment: Just glancing at Access datatypes, I see 7 different types that are Number. Can you be at bit more specific and provide the schema of the table.

Comment: If the DB is disconnected then you need to store all transactions in memory or elsewhere until the DB connects and you can execute the necessary update statements. This can lead to overdrafts so it's better if you make the DB calls in real-time. Every ATM I've ever used dials up to the internet and does this.

Comment: Stop using MS Access and use SQL Server LocalDB instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15